# WSO2: web service changePasswordByUser error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I've install a WSO2 API-M 1.10.0 and try to update the password of a user.

Steps:

- Create a user in the tenant "carbon.super" and assign the user admin role at the same time.(success)
- Using the credential of the user to change his password via web
  service UserAdminService changePasswordByUser.(fail)

The request is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <xsd:changePasswordByUser>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xsd:userName>?</xsd:userName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xsd:oldPassword>?</xsd:oldPassword>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xsd:newPassword>?</xsd:newPassword>
      </xsd:changePasswordByUser>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And the error message is :

```
Error while updating password. Wrong old credential provided
```

I'm sure that the two passwords are correct and the credential is base64 encoded(account:oldPassword).Am I try to encode the passwords into something??

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified this scenario and it is working fine in both APIM 1.10.0 and 2.0.0. If you get that error that means the password has already been changed and your are trying to change it for the second time. Please try to login to the management console using the new password and make sure it has been changed.

Comment: My scenario is wrong. What I really done is create a new tenant and do the above steps, so..the error occurs just on a new tenant. Thanks for testing.

Comment: The other issue about update roles is the same condition. I try to operate on carbon.super is working fine.